# Iterating through a list to separate items into multiple lists - Python

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have a list that contains a customer name, sale amount, and an item sold at a business.

The list transactions_clean has these three items

Now I want to separate these into three separate lists:

```
customers = []
sales = []
items = []
```

in another example I was working with the following worked perfectly

```
for customer in transactions_clean:
  customers.append(customer[0])
for sale in transactions_clean:
  sales.append(sale[1])
for item in transactions_clean:
  items.append(item[2])
```

When it used this for another list, it separated the items in their full length in each list. However, in this example for the customers name it is only separating it by individual characters into the customers list. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am somewhat new to Python. Note: this is not for homework, and it is not for work either, it is just me in my time trying to pick up a new language.

Thank you

Comment: This question is a bit hard to follow. Can you show us your input, the code you're using to process it, your expected output, and the output you're actually getting please?

Comment: the information in the list "transactions_clean" looks like the following:                      ```['Edith Mcbride', '$1.21', 'white', '09/15/17']``` repeated over and over again. Say if I do ```print(customers)``` I get the following ```['E', '$', 'w', '0', 'H', '$', 'w', '0', 'P', '$', 'w', '0', 'L', '$', 'w', '0', 'E', '$', 'w', '0', 'D', '$', 'p', '0', 'S', '$', 'p', '0', 'S', '$', 'p']``` I had to cut each part a bit short due to the length.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you loop over a variable you need to know what type of variable it is. For example if we iterate over a list we get each list item individually:

```py
>>> customers = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry']
>>> for person in customers:
>>>    print(person)
tom
dick
harry
```

But if we iterate over a string we get each character individually:

```py
>>> purchase = 'wine'
>>> for letter in purchase:
>>>    print(letter)
w
i
n
e
```

It looks like you're iterating over a string when you expect to be iterating over a list. Try adapting something like this to your problem:

```py
>>> customer_transactions = [['tom', 10.99, 'bottle of wine'],
                             ['dick', 14.49, '400g blue stilton'],
                             ['harry', 5.00, 'six pack of fosters']]

>>> customers = []
>>> sales = []
>>> items = []

>>> for transaction in customer_transactions:
>>>     customers.append(transaction[0])
>>>     sales.append(transaction[1])
>>>     items.append(transaction[2])
```

Now since `customers`, `sales`, and `items` are all lists we can iterate over them too:

```py
# continued from last code block
>>> for person in customers:
>>>     print(f"Thank you, {person}.")
Thank you, tom.
Thank you, dick.
Thank you, harry.
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped. It makes code a lot easier to read as well doing all three appends in a single for loop than spreading it across three.